# restarting while loop in a game

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to write a rock-paper-scissors game in python.this is the code:

```
D_0 = {1: "rock", 2: "scissors", 3: "paper"}
from random import randint
play = False
name = input("What is your name?: ")
print("%s you have to pick among rock,paper and scissors." % name)

while play == False:
    p_1 = input("which one?")
    computer = D_0[randint(1, 3)]
    print("my choice is: ",computer)
    if p_1 == computer:
        print("it's a draw")
    elif p_1 == "scissors" and computer == "paper":
        print("you won!")
    elif p_1 == "paper" and computer == "scissors":
        print("you lost!")
    elif p_1 == "scissors" and computer == "rock":
        print("you lost!")
    elif p_1 == "rock" and computer == "paper":
        print("you lost!")
    elif p_1 == "rock" and computer == "scissors":
        print("you won!")
    elif p_1 == "paper" and computer == "rock":
        print("you won!")
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
    break
again = input("do you want another round?:")
if again == "yes":
    play = False
else:
    play = True
```

the program works well but I want it to ask the player whether or not he/she wants to do another round.If the answer is yes the program must restart the loop.
The problem is I don't know how to do that.I know it's probably related to True and False and I attempted to do something as you can see in the code but it didn't work.
please Help me.

Comment: try shift 4 blanks to your last 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix might be just putting your while loop as `True` and continuing to loop until you break the execution:

```
D_0 = {1: "rock", 2: "scissors", 3: "paper"}
from random import randint

name = input("What is your name?: ")
print("%s you have to pick among rock,paper and scissors." % name)

while True:
    p_1 = input("which one?")
    computer = D_0[randint(1, 3)]

    print("my choice is: ", computer)

    if p_1 == computer:
        print("it's a draw")
    elif p_1 == "scissors" and computer == "paper":
        print("you won!")
    elif p_1 == "paper" and computer == "scissors":
        print("you lost!")
    elif p_1 == "scissors" and computer == "rock":
        print("you lost!")
    elif p_1 == "rock" and computer == "paper":
        print("you lost!")
    elif p_1 == "rock" and computer == "scissors":
        print("you won!")
    elif p_1 == "paper" and computer == "rock":
        print("you won!")
    else:
        print("Invalid input")

    again = input("do you want another round?:")
    if again != "yes":
        break
```

Comment: It would be better using a list or dict of pair rather than using elif tree.

Comment: @Vikas Damodar    can you explain more?

Comment: like a `list_win["scissors papers",..]` and `list_lose=["paper scisssors", ...]` and then check like `p_1+" "+computer in list` can avoid elif tree.